# taxonomy query on front page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a custom taxonomy query that fails when the page is set to be the front page. When the page is not set to be the front, it executes without issue.

My client has a highly-customized WP install: custom post types, custom taxonomies and so on. The site contains a series of pages that all use the same custom template that runs a query on post-type. The results can filtered by taxonomy using a $_GET request.

All of this works as expected and without issue in nearly all situations; the exception is when the page in question is designated as the front page in Settings.

This is a multisite install so, for example, the regular url is www.example.com/dogs. The page would be at www.example.com/dogs/poodles. With a taxonomy parameter, the url becomes www.example.com/dogs/poodles?color=12.

But when I make the poodles page the front page, the url eliminates the page name, the url becomes www.example.com/dogs?color=12 and the result is a 'page not found'.

One other wrinkle is that, in production, the tax params can contain multiple terms and will be in an array. So that url now becomes www.example.com/dogs?color%5B0%5D=12&color%5B1%5D=14.

This throws up a couple of errors from wp-includes/formatting.php, both objecting to being fed an array instead of a string.

I thought that maybe the front page follows a different template hierarchical path than 'regular' pages, sending the request to default wp functions instead of my custom template and functions. But then I'm not sure if it's the template path at all because it all appears to adhere to the wp template hierarchy as long as there's no taxonomy query present. For example, a site front page is to first look for a front-page.php file. I added the file and, indeed, the page goes there - except when that tax query is present.

I'm stumped! Any and all ideas or suggestions welcomed!

Comment: Just to make sure... Do you have a page called Dogs, and a child page Poodles?

Comment: If you make a specific page `front` it stop using overlooks any previous templates and only uses `front-page.php` or `home.php`. If you're trying to modify some filtering on the homepage I suggest hooking into [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) unless I'm misunderstanding your question as there's much to digest...

Comment: @passatgt It's multisite so the site is /dogs and the page is /poodles.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Thanks for the note. Yes, as I mentioned, the page designated as 'front page' will use the `front-page.php` template - except when that taxonomy query is present. Could you help me understand how to use the `pre_get_posts` hook in this situation?